# How to perform GeoCode calculation bound to Razor textboxes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In ASP.NET MVC 3, using Razor view engine, I have a few textboxes that combine an address (like street, street nr, postalcode).

I want to call a Bing GeoCode webservice after I have enough information for the call (like length of street > 0, length street nr > 0, etc..). It would be nice to validate on client site if all the text boxes have enough information, and then do a postback (to the Controller). After the postback the results of the webservice call (a lat/long) must be shown in the View.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public class GeoCodeViewModel
{
    [StringLength(70, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new GeoCodeViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(GeoCodeViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // the model is not valid => redisplay the view so that 
            // the user can fix his errors
            return View(model);
        }

        // TODO: at this stage the model is valid => call the web service
        ...
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model GeoCodeViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Street)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Street)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Street)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PostCode)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PostCode)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PostCode)
    </div>
    <p><button type="submit">OK</button></p>
}
```

Comment: Thx Darin. But the call to the web service is done here as a postback, while I want the call to the web service still on the client machine (without postback). So summarized: the view must be in editable state and during textbox on exit a check must be done if there is enough minimal information and call the webservice. Is that possible ?

Comment: @PatrickPeters, how do you intend to call a web service located on different domain from javascript? Does the Bing API support JSONP?

Comment: The webservice is basic-HTTP (http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc). The routine to calc lat/long based on address has been wrapped in a seperate C# class (which hides the complexity of the call the WS).

Comment: @PatrickPeters, that's why you need to invoke the web service from the controller.